# How to initialize gracenote::GnString?

Tags: c++, gracenote

We have experimented GNSDK api with "C" code and "Console Application", it's OK, now, we are experimenting GNSDK wrappers with "C++" code and Qt 5.1, we are stopped by this simple line :

```cpp
gracenote::GnString s_MyString = "another string";
```

How to make this line correct ?

Comment: Please define "we are stopped"...

Comment: After initialize gracenote::gnsdk ok, we have generate a windows file containing a string generated by a previous RegisterUser. Now we have reloaded this file (with Qt5.1 QFile::read) and we are trying to convert "QString from QT" to a gracenote::GnString. Here our application crashs without message !!!

gracenote::GnString skeyuser = (gracenote::GnString)0; // ok
// Below fatal instruction
skeyuser = (gracenote::GnString) buf.data();  // CRASH !!!

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title - if you have an answer, accept it, or if you've solved it yourself and the answer may be useful to others, answer it yourself, then accept it. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/218740) for a relevant discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GnString from GNSDK is only used for managed strings coming *out* of the SDK. There are only a few instances where it is used, returning serialized GnUser data being one. All other strings to and from GNSDK are 'C' strings (direct string pointers). GNSDK types these as gnsdk_cstr_t.

For passing the serialized string into RegisterUser just give it the 'C' string (but ensure it is UTF8 encoded).

From QString, you should be able to do this:

```
gnsdk_cstr_t serializedUser = text.toUtf8().constData();
```

You can pass this serializedUser into RegisterUser.

In short, you should not have to create GnString for use in your app. It's only there for certain output values from GNSDK.